# Xdebug with nginx failed to load extension

Tags: php, netbeans, nginx, xdebug

I installed php 5.4.0 and nginx 1.0.14 on windows 7.

When i want to install xdebug i downloaded xdebug 2.20(new for 5.4.0) and then i copied dll into my "php ext" folder.After that i added these lines in php.ini file.

```
zend_extension = C:\nginx\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll 

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9900
```

but when i started nginx it seems "Failed loading C:\nginx\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll" but the folder and file is correct.

But when i tried to change "`zend_extension = C:\nginx\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll`" with "`zend_extension_ts = C:\nginx\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll`" it didnt seem any error but my `phpinfo()` file doesnt seem xdebug installed.

How can i run it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should no longer use zend_extension_ts, but just zend_extension. The _ts and _debug postfixes have been removed in PHP 5.3. If you see "failed loading" it's most likely that you use the wrong binary. Please refer to http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php to see which one you need.